# Hamiltonian set of equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, hamilton-equations

I'm learning differential equations and trying to solve the following problem:

> $x_1'=x_2^2$
>
> $x_2'=x_4+x_3$
>
> $x_3'=x_4^2$
>
> $x_4'=x_1-x_2+x_3^2$
>
> We want to determine whether the system of equations is Hamiltonian.

I verified the necessary condition, which is:

$\frac{\partial fj}{\partial xj}=-\frac{\partial fi}{\partial xi}$ for each $i \neq j$.

I am looking for pairs but the $\frac{\partial fj}{\partial xj}=0$ for every $j$. I'm not sure how to continue in this case.

Could you please help me?